# Use text.get() as an argument in function

Tags: python, function, tkinter, text, arguments

How to use content into 'text_first' as argument 'source' and content into 'text_second' as argument 'direction' in function 'encrypt_file' ?
I tried to do like in code below, but it doesnt work.
Appreciate your any reply.

```
# file name fields
text_first = Text(
    font='Arial 14',
)
text_first.place(x=20, y=150, height=33, width=520)
text_second = Text(
    font='Arial 14',
)
text_second.place(x=20, y=275, height=33, width=520 )
text_third = Text(
    font='Arial 14',
)
text_third.place(x=20, y=400, height=33, width=520)

# update button
def encrypt_file_data(key, data):
    fn = Fernet(key)
    return fn.encrypt(data)
def encrypt_file(key, source, destination):
    with open(source, 'rb') as file:
        file_data = file.read()
        encrypted = encrypt_file_data(key,file_data)
    with open(destination, 'wb') as file:
        file.write(encrypted)
tkinter.Button(
    text='Update erstellen',
    width=93,
    height=3,
    font=('Arial', 10, 'bold'),
    command=lambda: encrypt_file('M-Gx3UOPC2B8Xo6smM8MyMU51aP8aoKEyrz-ZkUdpOI=', source=text_first.get('1.0', 'end-1c'), destination=text_second.get('1.0', 'end-1c')
).place(x=20, y=490)

tkinter.mainloop()
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Why do you think it doesn't work? I strongly encourage you to create a function for your button instead of stuffing code into a `lambda`. It will be much easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to write your code? I'd recommend a proper IDE like PyCharm which can help pick up errors like this. Everything is correct, but you're missing a closing bracket on your button. Should be:

```
tkinter.Button(
    text='Update erstellen',
    width=93,
    height=3,
    font=('Arial', 10, 'bold'),
    command=lambda: encrypt_file('M-Gx3UOPC2B8Xo6smM8MyMU51aP8aoKEyrz-ZkUdpOI=', source=text_first.get('1.0', 'end-1c'),
                                 destination=text_second.get('1.0', 'end-1c')
                                 )).place(x=20, y=490)
```

Without it you're trying to call place on the lambda function, not the button object.